# jasperreports - pdf font bold displays normal font only

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, ireport

I've read a lot of issues about this. They suggest to use font extensions, but my version of jasperreports is **3.1.0**. According to what I read font extensions are not added to this version of JR. So what can I do to display bold field in my report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who come across this problem (confusion), I just relied on the obsolete `Pdf Font Name` in the textfields property in iReport. Just ignore the iReport's deprecated warning because it seems like this is the only way